# Theorem euclid_gcd , proving that forall a b z, euclid a b z -> gcd a b z. using coq

Tags: coq, greatest-common-divisor

i am trying to prove euclid_gcd Theorem but i get stack in the first case !! some help please  :)

```
Inductive euclid : nat -> nat -> nat -> Prop :=
| stop : forall z, euclid z z z
| step_a : forall a b z, a > b -> euclid (a - b) b z -> euclid a b z
| step_b : forall a b z, a < b -> euclid a (b - a) z -> euclid a b z.

Inductive gcd : nat -> nat -> nat -> Prop :=
| base : forall z, gcd z z z
| step_a' : forall a b z, gcd a b z -> gcd (a + b) b z
| step_b' : forall a b z, gcd a b z -> gcd a (a + b) z.


Theorem euclid_gcd : forall a b z, euclid a b z -> gcd a b z.
Proof.
intros a b z H.
induction a.
....`
```

Answer (score 1):

I find out how to prove this Theorem . The induction must be at H So we have something to work with  ,

```
Theorem euclid_gcd : forall a b z, euclid a b z -> gcd a b z.
Proof.
intros a b z H.
induction H.
 - apply base.
 - apply step_a' in ....
```

Comment: Yes, this is a great answer: when you define a computing process as an inductive definition, the inductive principle associated to this inductive definition is a strong tool for reasoning about it!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write euclid as a function and gcd as a bunch of properties about that function.

As you may expect these basic concepts are already part of many Coq libraries. Here how "step_a'" looks like in Mathematical Components:
https://math-comp.github.io/htmldoc/mathcomp.ssreflect.div.html#gcdnDl

The key property of gcd (the function computing Euclidian division) is a showcase proof in this book, page 110:
https://zenodo.org/record/4457887#.YgKCdvso8RA

Comment: Hi , thank you for answering so fast . I cant change them to function , I am trying to understand how to work with inductive .